# Change the class of columns in a data frame

Tags: class, r

First of all, excuse me if I do any mistakes, but English is not a language I use very often.

I have a data frame with numbers. A small part of the data frame is this:

nominal     2
2
2
2

ordinal
2
1
1
2

So, I want to use the gower distance function on these numbers.

Here ( http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_man-2.9.0/library/StatMatch/man/gower.dist.html ) says that in order to use gower.dist, all nominal variables must be of class "factor" and all ordinal variables of class "ordered".

By default, all the columns are of class "integer" and mode "numeric". In order to change the class of the columns, i use these commands:

```
 DF=read.table("clipboard",header=TRUE,sep="\t")      
 # I select all the cells and I copy them to the clipboard. 
 #Then R, with this command, reads the data from there.

 MyHeader=names(DF)     # I save the headers of the data frame to a temp matrix

 for (i in 1:length(DF))  {
     if (MyHeader[[i]]=="nominal") DF[[i]]=as.factor(DF[[i]])
 }     

 for (i in 1:length(DF))  {
     if (MyHeader[[i]]=="ordinal") DF[[i]]=as.ordered(DF[[i]])
 }
```

The first for/if loop changes the class from integer to factor, which is what I want, but the second changes the class of ordinal variables to: "ordered" "factor".

I need to change all the columns with the header "ordinal" to "ordered", as the gower.dist function says.

Thanks in advance,
B.T.

Comment: Have you read (at least) the 'An Introduction to R' manual that came with R?

Comment: I'd vote down your pissy comment if I could. A website devoted to Q&A is not the place for RTFM.

Comment: @Brandon: actually, it is the best answer. The way the indices are used here hurts my eyes. Dirk isn't famous for his subtlety (nor am I btw). But SO would be a less interesting place without him, as he's here often and he's almost always right. Even when he tells you to RTFM.

Comment: @Joris, RTFM isn't a horrible thing in itself when provided with direction to what the OP is looking for and would likely get you rep too if given as a thoughtful answer. When the OP starts off by saying "sorry for my English", I think a bit more tact could be used. We all have a lot of respect for Dirk, myself included that's not at issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is fine --- if perhaps a little inelegantly.

With your ordered factor, you have something like:

```
> foo <- as.ordered(1:10)
> foo
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9 < 10
> class(foo)
[1] "ordered" "factor"
```

Notice that it has two classes, indicating that it *is* an **ordered** factor and that is *is* a **factor**:

```
> is.ordered(as.ordered(1:10))
[1] TRUE
> is.factor(as.ordered(1:10))
[1] TRUE
```

In some senses, you might like to think that `foo` is an ordered factor but also inherits from the factor class too. Alternatively, if there isn't a specific method that handles ordered factors, but there is a method for factors, R will use the factor method. As far as R is concerned, an ordered factor is an object with classes `"ordered"` and `"factor"`. This is what your function for Gower's distance will require.

Comment: @billyt: That wasn't your question. You need to confirm whether the gower distance function you are using in R is doing the same thing as the Matlab one. There are several variations of this coefficient out there. Start by reading `?gower.dist`. Alternatively, try function `daisy()` in package cluster, and I have a version in my analogue package in function `distance()`. There are others... Very little we can do here as we don't have your data nor the Matlab code.

Comment: Thanks, Gavin, for the reply. I did what you suggested but I still have a problem. By doing what you suggested, I have columns of class "factor" and columns of class "ordered" "factor". The results that I got are different than if I turned all the columns of class "factor". But still, a colleague of mine applied the Gower distance function on the same data using Matlab and she got different results from the matrix I got using the R tool. She changed the class of the data in a similar way to what I posted at the first post.

Comment: I didn't ask from her the Matlab code, but I guess they do the same thing. But I understand what you are saying. If I don't give you all the data, you can't do many things.

Comment: Don't assume that Matlab is doing the same thing! `daisy()` and `gower.dist()` treat ordered factors differently to unordered factors and this represents an extension of Gower's original coefficient. It is no wonder you get different results in R whether you use ordered factors of simple factors because those two types of data are handled differently - ordered factors can be represented by their ranks and used quantitatively (although in a different way to that for true quantitative data in Gower's coefficient). I know for a fact that my `distance()` and `daisy()` work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do this with:

```
DF$nominal <- as.factor(DF$nominal)
DF$ordinal <- as.ordered(DF$ordinal)
```

which gives you a dataframe with the correct structure. If you work with data frames, please stay away from `[[]]` unless you know very well what you're doing. Take Dirks advice, and check [Owen's R Guide](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Owen-TheRGuide.pdf) as well. You definitely need it.

If i do the conversion as I showed above, `gower.dist()` works perfectly fine. On a sidenote, the gowers distance can easily be calculated using the `daisy()` function as well:

```
DF <- data.frame(
    ordinal= c(1,2,3,1,2,1),
    nominal= c(2,2,2,2,2,2)
)
DF$nominal <- as.factor(DF$nominal)
DF$ordinal <- as.ordered(DF$ordinal)

library(cluster)
daisy(DF,metric="gower")
library(StatMatch)
gower.dist(DF)
```

Comment: Thanks, Joris, for the help. I know that the [[]] thing is tricky, but it is nessecary because my data has 28 columns and the "as.factor" and "as.ordered" commands change the class only the first columns, whereas the for/if loop manages to change them all. But with gower.dist() and daisy(), after I have changed the class of the data successfully, give me different results.